# How to execute certain part of the code in a While-Loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, keyboard

This is a modified working section of my code just to make it simple.

The idea is that the user enters from the main menu to a submenu, and there is asked to press ENTER to continue or ESC to return to the main menu.
When the user presses ENTER he/she should see QUESTION #1 and be able to perform some stuff, once that is done, another question, QUESTION #2 should pop up and ask if the user wants to perform stuff again or not.
If the user decides yes, then the loop continues and returns to QUESTION #1, otherwise, the loop breaks and returns to the main menu.
Everything is fine til that point.

However, if the user makes a mistake in QUESTION #2 and instead of inserting 'y' or 'n' inserts something else, i.e 'nm' or 'yt', etc. the loop at the moment breaks and returns them to the main menu. If I use Continue it will restart the loop and the user is obligated to perform stuff again.

I want to be able to bypass QUESTION #1 when the user inputs something wrong that is not 'y' or 'n' and asks me again to retry directly from QUESTION #2

```
import msvcrt
import time

#FUNCTIONS
def menu_options():
    print("MAIN MENU Options")

def option_sub01():
    print("SUB MENU Options, press ENTER to continue or ESC twice to exit")

def option01():   
    while True:
        #QUESTION #1 
        print("Question #1")

        #do stuff#
        print("doing stuff...")
        time.sleep(3)
        
        #QUESTION #2
        check = input("""Question #2, 
        press 'y' to continue loop and do stuff again, or 'n' to break loop and return to main menu.""")
        if check == 'y':                                              
            continue
        elif check == 'n':
            break
        else:
            print("Wrong Input.")
            break #breaks the loop and returns to main menu if user inputs any other letter that is not Y or N.
           #continue continues the loop but instead of asking the user to try again, it restart the whole loop and the user is obligated to answer QUESTION #1.

#START
while True:
    menu_options()
    
    o = input("Choose an option (only option 1 works): ")

    if o == '1':
        option_sub01()
        if ord(msvcrt.getch()) == 13:
            option01()
            print()
        elif ord(msvcrt.getch()) == 27: #For some reason I must press ESC key twice for it to work.
            continue
        else:
            print("Wrong input.")
```

Bonus issue: I do not understand why Python makes me press the ESC key twice for it to work, and the key ENTER works at once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you should be able to make another `while` loop before the `input`. If `check` is 'y', break out of the second `while` loop. If `check` is 'n', break out of both while loops, possibly by storing a `boolean` in a variable. If `check` is neither 'y' or 'n', continue and let it loop through the input again. If you'd like I can draft up some code and put it as an answer.

Comment: Yes please, I feel you are in the right track. I tried the nested loops but did not work. But I haven't tried the boolean as you mentioned, mainly because I had no idea.

Comment: I very well could have it wrong, let me do some experimenting and I'll post my results in the answers section.

Comment: Just some advice, I would recommend giving your variables, such as `o`, more descriptive names, such as `option`. Even if it is painfully obvious what `o` stands for given it's definition, it will make it more memorable, easier for you tow work with, and easier for anyone else viewing your code to understand what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a variable called `reset` which, under the right circumstances, would allow the user to break out of both loops. Here is some code you can use to implement it:

```
import time


def task():
    while True:
        reset = False
        
        print('QUESTION #1')
        # Do some stuff
        time.sleep(3)
        
        while True:
            check = input("""Question #2,
                  press 'y' to continue loop and do stuff again, or 'n' to break loop and return to main menu.""").lower()

            if check == 'y':
                break
            elif check == 'n':
                reset = True
                break
            else:
                print('Invalid input, please try again!')
                time.sleep(3)
                continue
            
        if reset:
            break


task()
```

Hope this helps.